# Do shares survive changes in drive letter?

Tags: windows, share

Using robocopy to mirror (with security) physical drive E: to iSCSI drive G: Once this is complete, I was planning to make sure there are no open file handles or sessions (it's a file share server) and then:

1. Delete drive letter E:
2. Rename drive letter G: to E:

At step #1, will the shares (upon which DFS is reliant) stay intact or will they get deleted/broken?

Answer (score 2):

Yes the shares are associated with the drive letter and/or mount point.

I have used a procedure similar to that in the past when moving to a different type of storage.  I replicate the data, stop the server service, shuffle the drive letters or mount points around, and restart the Server service.

You mention DFS, are you doing an DFS replication.  I am pretty sure that drive letter swap would completely screw up replication, but I don't have any good references to support that belief.  If you are only using DFS for namespace purposes then it shouldn't matter.

Comment: We are using DFS namespaces and DFS replication but the two aren't connected (e.g. replication not published/link to namespace). I was planning to stop the DFSR service as well - it uses drive letters so I guessed E:\Data would still work after jiggling letters around

Comment: If you are using DFS-R I believe you would have to disable/remove the replica.  Then re-add it when you are done with shuffling things around.  When you copy the data, make sure you do it correctly, or you will have a massive resync.  This blog describes the steps required to [Replacing DFSR Member Hardware](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2010/09/07/replacing-dfsr-member-hardware-or-os-part-2-pre-seeding.aspx).  I believe you would have to follow those steps here to make sure your replica is valid.